# Execute a Python script from another Python script with argparse input argument and extract an output

Tags: python, subprocess, argparse

Given:

`child.py`:

```
import argparse
import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A sample script with argparse')
parser.add_argument('--query', type=str, help='Query Phrase', default="I love coding!")
args = parser.parse_args()

def customized_fcn(inp="This is my sample text!"):
    result=inp.split()
    return result

def main():
    my_splited_text=customized_fcn(inp=args.query)

    # Serialize the list into a string and print it
    serialized_result = json.dumps(my_splited_text)
    print('Serialized Result:', serialized_result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I would like to capture/extract `my_splited_text` with type `<class 'list'>` from `child.py` in another script called `parent.py` as follows:

```
import subprocess
import json
import re

def run_my_script():
    command = ['python', 'child.py', '--query', 'I want to eat an ice-cream right now!']
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    return_code = process.wait()
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

    # Extract and deserialize the result
    serialized_result = re.search(r'Serialized Result: (.+)', stdout).group(1)
    my_splited_text=json.loads(serialized_result)
    print('Captured Result:', type(my_splited_text), my_splited_text)

run_my_script()
```

Right now I use `json` to first serialize the `my_splited_text` into a string representation in `child.py` and then extract and deserialize the result in `parent.py` to be able to use it in the rest of my code.

I wonder if there exists an easier and better approach than this serialization or deserialization ?

Comment: "I wonder if there exists an easier and better approach than this serialization or deserialization ?" - it's not possible to answer this without understanding your specific needs for serialization. On the other hand, it *does not matter* how you set up the subprocess call, or whether you have a client-server architecture, etc. - serialization is serialization.

Comment: do you need to use argparse or do you just want to pass stuff from parent to child ? if you can bypass the argparse you can use `multiprocessing`, which is a lot faster than using json and the disk.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I actually need to use argparse ! my main intention is to use `my_splited_text` in `parent.py` for other purposes in the rest of my code!

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I just came up with serialization solution but I thought there might still exist more straight-forward approaches to deal with this

Comment: To be clear: it should probably use *some kind of* serialization. But there are countless ways to do it, and there is not enough information here to decide. (Keep in mind the [subjectivity guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), too.)